# drawing a wall in a snake game java

Tags: java

i'm trying to draw a wall for my snake game, i did it thanks to the paintComponent method, i'm just wondering if there is some way of drawing the wall once and not redrawing it repetidly every time paintComponent method is called.

I tried a boolean that stops the method from redrawing the wall once done the first time, but this doesnt work since paintComponent removes all and redraws it all.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(drawWall) {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.getWidth(); i++) {
            g.drawImage(wall.getWallImage(), i*32, 0, this);
        }
        drawWall = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Draw the wall to a `BufferedImage` and then paint the `BufferedImage` using `Graphics#drawImage`

Comment: Also known as [double buffering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html).

Comment: @PaulRichter Well, technically, it's more like triple buffering, considering Swing components are already double buffered, but it does reduce the overhead of painting the walls in a loop and is generally more efficient ;)

Comment: Oh I see! I wasn't aware of that, Cool. Looks like that's explained [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), from what I can determine. Thanks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, this will draw the wall once or it will redraw it everytime but reduce access to the processor?